# How Should a has-many Association Behave When A Record That is Already Present Is Added?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

I'm trying to work through a more complex issue, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer regarding the way `has_many` handles situations where an object already present in the association is added again.

What is the expected behaviour in the following situation (where `alpha` has many `betas`:

```
alpha.betas << beta_1
alpha.betas << beta_1
```

**Should the second insertion be silently ignored (ensuring only unique betas in alpha's association?)**

Comment: nope it would reference it twice

Comment: @GauravShah Thanks. So what would be the correct pattern to use to ensure only records that aren't present are added. Checking if the record is already in the association whenever adding seems like a poor answer.

Comment: If you do `alpha.betas = beta_1`  It will make the association only the objects in beta_1 by adding and deleting.  I don't know if that's helpful for you.

Comment: @Pedr I am not aware of a better answer. If your backend was mongo you could stuff like `$addToSet` not sure whats your backend

Answer (score 1):

The docs state the following:

> collection<<(object, …)
>   Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the collection's primary key. Note that this operation instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object, unless the parent object is a new record.

So my understanding is, that the object is referenced only once. It is therefor only once in the active_record relation `alpha.betas`. If you call it again, the foreign_key is set again, to the same value it already has. So this changes nothing.